# Why do ServiceStack examples usually have a function definition of "object Any"

Tags: servicestack

I notice most if not all ServiceStack example have services of this form:

`public object Any(Request request) { }`

Even if the function is always returning an integer.

Why declare the function as `public object Any` rather than `public int Any` or is this just a stylistic choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, [Services should only return Reference Types](https://docs.servicestack.net/service-return-types#services-should-only-return-reference-types) so you would need to either wrap value types in a Response DTO or return it in a string.

The reason for using `object` is because the return type of Service methods has no effect, you should instead use the `IReturn<T>` interface marker on your Request DTOs to annotate the response of your API so this important type information is available to all clients and API consumers, e.g:

```cs
public class Request : IGet, IReturn<Response> {}
```

So we recommend using `object` to remove any confusion that the return Type of a Service method implementation has any effect or is ever used in Metadata Services, instead all information about the API should be annotated on the Request DTO which is what defines your API's Service Contract.

The other benefit of using `object` is that it lets you return the Response DTO or a decorated Response DTO, e.g:

```cs
public object Any(Request request) 
{
    if (ShouldAddHeader(request, out var name, out var value))
    {
        return new HttpResult(response) { 
            Headers = { [name] = value }
        }
    }    
    return new Response();
}
```

From an API perspective the Response Type, which defines the serialize type returned in the HTTP Response body of the API remains the same. This wouldn't be possible if strong types were used.

Also there's many cases when return type of a service method doesn't match the API Response type, when returning a decorated `HttpResult`, when returning any binary response like: `Stream`, `Image`, `IStreamWriter`, `ReadOnlyMemory<byte>`, etc. the API Response is always `byte[]`

A good place to learn more general information about Services is in the [API Design](https://docs.servicestack.net/api-design) and [Service Return Types](https://docs.servicestack.net/service-return-types) docs.

Comment: Thanks @mythz, I was going to ask, why does the "HelloService" do this then: `public string Get(HelloHtml request)` - but then I looked at the doc is not aligned with the source.

Answer (score 1):

ServiceStack takes a [message based](https://docs.servicestack.net/architecture-overview) approach in its design, meaning that Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) are central to how to declare your Service contracts using your Request and Response DTO classes.

To quote the documentation:

> The primary difference between developing RPC vs ServiceStack's Message-based Services is that the Services entire contract is defined by its typed messages, specifically the Request DTO which defines both the System inputs and identifies the System output. Typically both are POCO DTOs however the response can be any **serializable object**.

Request DTOs should be declared with an `IReturn<T>` where `T` is your Response DTO. This maximizes interoperability between different client languages, message formats etc. For example:

```
[Route("/hello/{Name}")]
public class Hello : IReturn<HelloResponse>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class HelloResponse
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
```

This now means your Request & Response DTO now show the structure of the messages your service accepts and returns. This approach then drives features like [Add ServiceStack Reference](https://docs.servicestack.net/add-servicestack-reference) which can generate the Request and Response DTO in 9 supported languages since the messages are all easy to represent with a `class`.

The ServiceStack docs also have a good page on [What is a message based Web Service](https://docs.servicestack.net/what-is-a-message-based-web-service).